# Login Custom TextInput and Pressable not working after logout

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-component

This is my **Navigation**

```
import React from 'react'

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'

import { Login } from '../views/Login'
import { Home } from '../views/modules/Home'


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export { Navigation }
```

This is my **Login**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native'
import FormData from 'form-data'
import { CustomInput } from '../components/CustomInput'
import { CustomButton } from '../components/CustomButton'
import { CustomModalAlert } from '../components/CustomModalAlert'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

const Login = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation() 
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false) 
    const [code, setCode] = useState("") 
    const setModalData = (data) => { 
        setShowModal(data.bool) 
        if (data.bool) { 
            navigation.navigate('Home') 
        } 
    }

    const submitLoginForm = () => {
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("code", code);
        fetch("http://192.168.3.200/mobile_login/api", { 
            method  : 'POST', 
            headers : { 
                'Accept': 'application/json', 
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 
            }, 
            body    : data, 
        }) 
        .then((res)=>res.json()) 
        .then((res)=>{ 
            if (res.success == 1) { 
                setShowModal(true)
            } else { 
                Alert.alert(
                    "Opps!",
                    res.message,
                    [{ text: "OK" }]
                )
            } 
        }) 
        .catch((err) => {
            Alert.alert(
                "Network Error!",
                "Please check your internet connection",
                [{ text: "OK" }]
            )
        })

    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}> 
            <CustomInput 
                placeholder='Code'
                autoFocus={true} 
                value={code} 
                onChangeText={(code) => setCode(code)}
            />
            <CustomButton 
                text={'LOG IN'} 
                onPress={() => submitLoginForm()}
            />
            <CustomModalAlert 
                setData={setModalData} 
                showModal={showModal} 
                title={'Confirmation'}
                text={'Go to Home?'}
                cancelButtonLabel={'Cancel'}
                confirmButtonLabel={'Confirm'}
            /> 
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1, 
        justifyContent: 'center', 
        alignItems: 'center', 
    }, 
})

export { Login }
```

This is **Home**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { CustomModalAlert } from '../../components/CustomModalAlert'
import { CustomFloatingLogout } from '../../components/CustomFloatingLogout'

const Home = () => {

    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false) 
    const navigation = useNavigation() 
    const logout = () => {
        setShowModal(true)
    }
    const setModalData = (data) => { 
        setShowModal(data.bool) 
        if (data.bool) { 
            navigation.navigate('Login') 
        } 
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text><Icon name="person" size={30} /></Text>
            <Text>Home</Text>
            <CustomFloatingLogout onPress={() => logout()} />
            <CustomModalAlert 
                setData={setModalData} 
                showModal={showModal} 
                title={'Logout?'}
                text={'Go to Home?'}
                cancelButtonLabel={'Cancel'}
                confirmButtonLabel={'Yes, Log Out!'}
            /> 
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({ container: { flex: 1, }, })

export { Home }
```

[Login View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9vZE.png)
[Home View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDBH8.png)

When I click the login button in **Login View** then Ok the popup modal, it goes to the Home View and the homes floating button is working then when I click the **Home View** floating button to logout it goes to Login View but **the TextInput and Button is not working**

The question is how can I make TextInput and Button work?

Sorry, I'm new in react-native. Thanks for help.

Comment: which function is getting called on click of `'Yes, Log Out!'` label ? Can you please include that also

Comment: looks like you have opened the model but haven't closed it.

Comment: It works @Kailash, I forgot to close the modal lol. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have opened Modal but you haven't closed. So its causing this issue.

**Reason:** If you have used transparent modal and then click on navigate to other screen, in this case if the Modal is still opened, then you will see the new screen but you won't be able to click it, because of transparent modal.

In your case you should be setting your `showModal` state to false, once click on the label `'Yes, Log Out!'`. And do the same for your Login Module as well, if not closed.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved and will answer my question  thanks to @Kailash

```
const setModalData = (data) => { 
        setShowModal(data.bool)
        if (data.bool) { 
            setShowModal(false) 
            props.navigation.navigate('Home') 
        } 
    }
```

I just added

```
setShowModal(false)
```

under

```
if (data.bool) {
```

in **Login**

The problem is I forgot to close the modal before navigating.